# Checkbox always returns false

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox

I have a form populated with items from a table. Each item has a checkbox which allows the user to request that item after clicking a button. Requested is the checkbox. I've tried  `Me!Requested = 0`, and that gives the same result.

The problem is that the checkbox value always returns false even when it is checked. Referring to the code, I always get the first message.

```
Private Sub btnSubmitRequest_Click()

If Me!Requested = False Then
    MsgBox ("Please select at least 1 item to check out.")
    Exit Sub
Else
   MsgBox ("123")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Me!Requested.Value = False just add .Value after

Comment: I tried that and I get the same result.

Comment: Try Me.Requested.Value = False instead of "!"

Comment: Is this a continuous form? I wonder about the "Please select **at least** 1 item" part. `Me!Requested` will only evaluate the current record. Please add a screenshot of your form (upload to imgur.com and add the link).

Comment: Here is the link: http://imgur.com/fOHxOxU

Comment: Regarding the image above, only one record is showing because of testing purposes. There will be several records populated in the final form.

Comment: I would use `me.Requested =false` with a full stop rather than an exclamation. That's what I appear to have used in the past and is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote above, `Me!Requested` will only look at the `Requested` checkbox **in the current record**. So whatever random value it has, will determine the outcome.

If you want to check that **at least one** `Requested` checkbox is selected, you need to look at all of them. You can do this e.g. with a loop over `Me.RecordsetClone`, e.g.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim nSelected As Long

nSelected = 0
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If rs!Requested = True Then
        nSelected = nSelected + 1
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

MsgBox "Selected: " & nSelected
```

Comment: That makes sense, however the message says that I've selected 0 records even when I check a box.

Comment: @duberry: Have you saved the record? What if you check multiple boxes? This will help: [How to debug your VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I have checked multiple boxes. Strangely, the code only works when there is one record populated in the form. For example, as you can see from the screenshot, I have buttons for filtering the records. The "Tools" filter only show one record, because I only have one tool listed in the table. When I select the single tool and then click the Submit Request button, the message will say that I selected 1 record. If I switch the filters or check any other boxes, the message will say that I selected 0 records.